# Azure Service Bus Virtual Network added to Firewall but still getting 401 Ip has been prevented to connect to the endpoint

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-virtual-network

End users initially hit with 401 response:

> Ip has been prevented to connect to the endpoint

To address, the connection point was in **another subscription** so we needed to add to the firewall.

1. Virtual Network Subnet needed to enable Service Endpoints.
2. Added subnet to the Service Bus Firewall.

Yet still users were hit with same 401 due to IP block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though UI allowed end user to configure the Service Bus VNET Subnet FW, ARM based operations were failing - indicating some deeper issue.

Ultimate fix was to enable Service Bus resource provider in the subscription where the subnet belonged.

Once enabled, this allowed the Service Bus VNET subnet firewall to correctly whitelist the source IP.